# UIScrollView touchesShouldCancelInContentView never gets called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Even with canCancelContentTouches=YES , I can never get touchesShouldCancelInContentView to get called from my UIScrollView subclass.  Any ideas?

Comment: you created a subclass, have you tried reverting back to a standard UIScrollView and seeing if there is a similar issue, my initial reaction is that you may have done something wrong in your subclass implementation

Comment: Matt is probably right. I don't know what you are doing with your subclass, but you might consider using a category on UIScrollView to add whatever functionality you are trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

Also set delaysContentTouches to NO:

`[myUIScrollViewSubclass setDelaysContentTouches:NO]`